# Making function that can get as parameter &var or var

Tags: c++, function, variables, pointers

I would like to create a function so I can use it in both ways -

I know that my wording is was not good so I deleted it (Because it will cause only confusion) and leaving only the code with the notes inside it:

```
int CalculationFunc(int i1, int i2, int i3, int i4, int i5) {
    /* Some calculation done here */
    return (i2*i3)+i5-i2+i4; /* <- this is not good example.. the calculation will be based also on
                             on values that are changing from time to time.. */
}

int main() {
// Situation 1:
    /* In this situation I didn't initialized any parameter before because I didn't
    need to.. all I need is to call to the functions with predefined values */
    int iAnswer1 = CalculationFunc(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    /*^ Everything is fine in this case - I Allocate memory only once*/

// ----------------------------------------------------------
// Situation 2:

    int iVal1 = 0, iVal3 = 0, iVal5 = 0; // <-- Memory is allocated 
    /* ... something done here so the values of are not constant ...
    (The code for this is not written) */


    /*In this situation something different: some values that I going to pass to the
    function are not predefined, and they are outcome of some pre-calculation done before,
    so there is allocated memory for them. If I call to the functions with these variables: */
    int iAnswer2 = CalculationFunc(iVal1, 6, iVal3, 2, iVal5);
    /* ^ There is not really a "real-world" problem here. the problem is that what happening
    In low-level is this:
        a) allocate memory for iVal1 , iVal3 , iVal5
        b) copy value of iVal1 to the allocated memory (and the same for iVal3 and iVal5)
        c) use the allocated memory..

    This is not efficient. What I want to do is to pass pointers for iVal1, iVal3, iVal5
    And the function will automatically get the data using the pointers. 
    So there will not be steps a and b.

    This is how I want to call it:
        CalculationFunc(&iVal1, 6, &iVal3, 2, &iVal5)
    */


    return 0;
}
```

**Thanks for helpers!**

Comment: Are you actually asking for reference parameters?

Comment: To improve your question, show code of how you set your variables up

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want an overloaded `MyFunc` that takes certain parameters as pointers? Do you just want to pass the value your pointers point to as arguments to `MyFunc`?

Comment: Please wait. I will write an example to explain myself better and edit the question. I'm sorry I was not clear. My English is not very good

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: passing pointers will be less efficient than passing ints ....  most likely a pointer is equal or bigger in size than an int, and then you have the cost of dereferencing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overload the function to take different sets of parameters as references (or plain pointers), but you would end up with a lot of unnecessary copies of the same piece of code.

If you are planning to do this just for the sake of performance, I advice you not to. You are probably not going to get any performance boost from that, not with such simple data types.

> This is better because this way the function does not necessarily require to allocate memory (for just a copy value) to transfer the same data.

When you're passing a variable by a reference or a pointer, the address to the variable needs to be copied. And when the data type of the variable you are referring to is int, the address is about the same size as the variable itself, so passing a pointer to an int is not any faster than passing the int itself. Actually, it is probably slower, because the pointer then needs to be dereferenced when the value is used in the function.

For a data type with larger size passing by pointer/reference could be significantly faster, but not with ints.

Comment: "You could overload the ..... piece of code." 
I know. That's why I thought to check if there is another solution that does not require me to overload many possible options.                  .  "When you're passing .......... in the function." Thank you for this. I never thought about it. I know it's not really serious for Int data type. but I assume as you mentioned that it may be  more serious for havy data type such as Array and string. I just want to know If there is an option to do it just for a case and for my knowledge. If there is no such option in C++ then fine..

Comment: @gil123 "I just want to know If there is an option to do it" - I don't think there is. Maybe the best way to do this (if it is necessary) would be to declare the function so that it takes references as parameters, and then declare every value that needs to be passed to the function as a variable (if it isn't one already) before calling the function. But that is not much better than the overloading either. You'd might also try to overload the function with versions that take different types of parameters, and then in those overloads just call the original function that takes only references.

Comment: About the overloading method, If I am going to duplicate almost all the code then it is fine (Assuming there is not a lot code in the function to duplicate ). but if not then I can't see how will be better. It's too much to explain. I do not know how to explain with my words.. but If you try it you may understand what I mean. Anyway, what you have specified about ints (In the context of this subject) Brought me to conclude that I probably would not really need this feature in the future (at least not in most of the time)